# Nodejs + Require instanceof behaviour

Tags: node.js, exception, require

I'm encountering a strange behaviour with instanceof in NodeJs. I'm trying to creating a module which throws exceptions which can be caught by consuming modules and dealt with based on the exception type. However the call to test the type "*error instanceof mod.MyException*" is always returning false.

**mymodule.js**:

```
function MyException() {}
MyException.prototype = new Error();
MyException.prototype.constructor = MyException;

function Foo() {
    throw new MyException();
}

exports.Foo = Foo;
exports.MyException = MyException;
```

**myconsumingmodule.js**

```
var mod = require('mymodule');

try {
    mod.Foo();
} catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof mod.MyException) { // always returns false
         //do error specific handling (never executes)
         return;
    }
    // generic handling
}
```

If I do the instanceof test in mymodule.js like so it returns true

**mymodule.js**

```
var a = new MyException()
console.log(a instanceof MyException); //true
```

However if I create an exception in the consuming module and test it it correctly identifies it as MyException, it just doesn't when comparing it against an exception that was created by the other module.

**myconsumingmodule.js**

```
var mod = require('mymodule')
var b = new mod.MyException();
console.log(b instanceof mod.MyException); // true
```

Comment: works for me on node 0.10.5

Comment: @Eriedor, have you ever found a solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't, I abandoned trying to solve this problem and haven't revisited it to see if it's fixed in a later version of node.

Comment: I'm running into this problem too. It's mind boggling. Makes zero sense

Answer (score 10):

FOUND IT

To use your example, in file `one.js` I had:

```
var mod = require('mymodule');
```

but in *another* file `two.js` I had:

```
var mod = require('Mymodule');
```

and everything seemed to work exactly the same, **except when you compared an error created from `one.js` using `instanceof` in `two.js`!**.

Absurdly, node.js allows you to do a case-insensitive require, except it's not really case-insensitive, it actually requires your file **twice**, which is why `instanceof` returns `false` – the constructors are two different functions from two different module instances!

**TL;DR**

Make sure all your `require` strings are case-consistent.

Comment: I wish I could give this more than one vote. After hours of researching this (which ended with most people answering some other question) I had just about given up. In one file I had the wrong case. Changed it and Voila! I'm bet you're on a Mac (like me) which has case-preserving, case-ignoring file system semantics. I don't think this is NodeJS' fault. Please mark this as the answer.

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning (because I just ran into it) is that different paths to the file will also have this effect. So `a/b/c.js` referencing `../../d.js` and `a/b.js` referencing `../d.js` will require `d.js` twice...

Comment: Tremendously helpful - solved my same, hard-to-diagnose issue. Thank you.  Like James Keesey, I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Wow, thank you! This answer just solved a massive headache for me.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce the problem. Working for me using version 0.12 and 4.0.0 (tested both).

What you should consider in future is that you reference your OWN modules using relative paths (absolute ones are not system independent). If you don't, you normally reference core modules of Node.js directly or NPM installed ones. So change 'mymodule' to './mymodule' (change path accordingly).